# JsPdf page break not working

Tags: jspdf, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have this very simple code that works with jspdf and html2pdf but for some reason jspdf is not breaking the elements into new pages.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Html2Pdf</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css">
<style>
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

table td {
  padding: 3px;
}

.table1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.table2,.table2 td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table2 td:first-child {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.CSSTableGenerator {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td {

}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffaa56;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.CSSTableGenerator td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td {
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td {
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff7f00", endColorstr="#bf5f00");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff7f00, bf5f00);
  background-color: #ff7f00;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td {
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff7f00", endColorstr="#bf5f00");
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff7f00, bf5f00);
  background-color: #ff7f00;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style='position: absolute'>
    <h1>Tables</h1>
    <table class='table1'>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Available</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="html2pdf__page-break"></div>
    <div>
    <table class='table2'>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Available</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <table class='CSSTableGenerator' style='page-break-before: always'>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Available</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Milk</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
        <td>Hello PDF World</td>
        <td>Out Of Stock</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  <script src='jspdf.debug.js'></script>
  <script src='html2pdf.js'></script>
  <script>

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var canvas = pdf.canvas;
        canvas.height = 96 * 11;
        canvas.width=96 * 8.5;;
        // var width = 400;
        html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function(pdf) {
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:900px');
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');

               //var div = document.createElement('pre');
               //div.innerText=pdf.output();
               //document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check my answer in this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366125/how-can-i-dynamically-add-page-breaks-in-jspdf-to-prevent-tables-from-breaking/75079680#75079680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsPDF` uses a special HTML tag...

```
<!--ADD_PAGE-->
```

...to force a page-break.
Please note that this only applies if using the `addHTML` method.
I had this exact problem and throwing in the tag worked perfectly.

Comment: Having this issue with the new `.html` method, any idea how to utilize page breaks there?

Comment: @Michael Same here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: went on to a new job since, but I IIRC we had to change the source code to make it work.

Comment: @Michael How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to dig in to the source code, I don't have access to this anymore, sorry

Comment: is there any option available in jspdf, I'm stuck here for the last week.

Comment: Anyone find this solution?

Comment: Guys, I have the same issue I need to page break if the text is cut

Answer (score 4):

set "autoPaging" and margin work for me on jsPDF html plugin

```js
doc.html(htmlEl, {
        callback: function(doc) {
        ...
        },
        autoPaging: 'text',
        margin: [12, 8, 15, 8],
        html2canvas: {
            scale: 0.9
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check this pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all'}, i have tested in multi page pdf consisting of 10+ pages. it works fine for me.

```
 var opt = {
        margin: 1, 
        filename: 'ontract.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: {scale:2 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
        pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all', after: '.avoidThisRow' }       
    };
```

Comment: try this new approach also add above options `html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').save()`